# how to disable download option on apexcharts?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

I am use [apexcharts vue bindings](https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/) to plot a few bar charts.

As told by docs it should be possible to disable the toolbar by set show:false as seen [there](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/toolbar/).

So i did it on my helper function:

```
// do-char-options.js
const randomColor = require("randomcolor");
module.exports = labels => ({
  toolbar: { show:false },// docs says it should do the trick
  colors: randomColor({
    luminosity: "light",
    hue: "blue",
    count: 30
  }),
  plotOptions: {
    bar: { distributed: true, horizontal: true }
  },
  tooltip: {
    theme: "dark"
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: labels,
    color: "white",
    labels: {
      style: {
        colors: ["white"]
      }
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: "white"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and i pass it to my vue component this way:

```
<template>
    <v-layout row justify-center wrap>
        <v-flex xs12>
            <apexchart type="bar" height="500" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"/>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
const doOptions = require("./do-chart-options");
const labels = [
    "Javascript",
    "Java",
    "SQL",
    "HTML",
    "CSS",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "GO",
    "Ruby"
];
module.exports = {
    name: "chart-languages",
    data: _ => ({
        series: [{ data: [160, 110, 90, 85, 80, 80, 60, 30, 15, 14, 9] }],
        chartOptions: doOptions(labels)
    })
};
</script>
```

However the menu is still there:

[image]

Any guidance is welcome.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`toolbar` should be under `chart` key

```
{
  chart: {
    toolbar: {
      show: false
    }
  },
  colors: randomColor({
    luminosity: "light",
    hue: "blue",
    count: 30
  }),
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      distributed: true,
      horizontal: true
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

You can check my demo [here](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/vvdamW)

Answer (score 9):

```
  chart: {
      toolbar: {
        show: true,
        tools:{
          download:false // <== line to add
        }
      }
    }
```

Can only disable download option , but toolbar exists

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS to hide the option(s) from the download section.

```
/* hide the Download CSV */

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  ::v-deep .apexcharts-menu-item.exportCSV {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was wanting to do.  In my vanilla CSS file, I just used this part and it worked for me: .apexcharts-menu-item.exportCSV {
    display: none;
  }

Answer (score 2):

edit this line may help you

```
{chart: {toolbar: {show: false
}},
  colors: randomColor({
    luminosity: "light",
    hue: "blue",
    count: 30
  }),
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      distributed: true,
      horizontal: true
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Please add details so users(including OP) understand why this would work in place of existing code.